# Firebase javascript security?

Tags: javascript, security, firebase

I am using the firebase storage and account system in my website. Thats why, I had to put some js codes (include api key). Can I hide this code. Because somebody can hack (create billions accounts or add billions files) my firebase with this api code. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

have a look at this Firecast that was released just yesterday that talks about this topic among other valuable security questions.

https://youtu.be/6sIZvHOEw6Q?t=138

TL;DR There is no reason to try to hide the key (and it's not possible either, since the browser will need it to use Firebase anyways)

Comment: Whoa, that was a quick downvote, care to explain?

Comment: Note sure why you attracted downvotes. I counter-upvoted, but also closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Quite ok Frank, was just curious. The Firecast is definitely worth a look for all similar questions however.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this looks superficially a lot like a link-only answer. It might be better to switch the structure around so that the TL;DR part is the main thing and the video recommendation is a side note.